# y axis labeling in R and how to change x-axis to specific increments in R

Tags: r

I would like to create a plot of [this data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1g8ZFtIqlJ-FHDW8OkU2WoaV0kLwOr51x), with x-axis increments of 500000 and with `sampleIDs` on the y-axis. The following code works to create the plot, but the y-axis labels don't work, and I am unsure how to code the x-axis ticks. Also, I had to add headings manually to the data file (and then obviously add `header = TRUE` when I assigned `d`) to get the code to work. I shouldn't have had to put the column titles in though should I since I use setNames?

```
   d = read.delim("n_reads_per_sample.tsv", header = TRUE, sep = "\t")

xticks <- ( ? increments of 500000 to xmax ? )
dotchart(
  sort(setNames(d$n_reads, d$X.sample)),
  xlim = c(0, at = xticks, 1 max(d$n_reads)),
  labels = dimnames(d[[1]])
  ,
  main = "reads per sample",
  xlab = "number of reads",
  ylab = "sample"
)
```

In case the link doesn't work, this is what the file looks like.

```
x.sample    n_reads
LT-145  3193621
LT-323  786578
LT-458  485543
LT-500  3689123
LT-95   3308764
LT-367  765972
LT-205  2090226
LT-245  10238727
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't get at your full data right now,  so I am just using your sample in the question. 
Not sure what you mean that the y-axis labels don't work. They seem OK to me.  You can get the x-axis labels that you want by suppressing the x-axis produced by `dotchart` and then making your own axis using the `axis` function.  That requires a little fancy footwork with `par`.  Also, unless you stretch out your graphics window, there will not be enough room to print all of the axis labels. I reduced the font size and stretched the window to get the graph below.

```
UpperLimit <- ceiling(max(d$n_reads)/500000)*500000
xticks <- seq(0,UpperLimit, 500000)

par(xaxt = "n")
dotchart(
  sort(setNames(d$n_reads, d$X.sample)),
  xlim=c(0, UpperLimit),
  labels = dimnames(d[[1]]),
  main = "reads per sample",
  xlab = "number of reads",
  ylab = "sample"
)
par(xaxt = "s")
axis(1, at=xticks, cex.axis=0.7)
```

[image: dotchart with specified x-axis ticks]

Comment: Great about the axis, thank you. So strange that dimnames works for you. I literally put in exactly your code and I still don't get y axis labels on my plot. When i type "d[[1]]" all the sample numbers are printed just fine. But when I type "labels = dimnames(d[[1]])" and then type "labels" to see that labels contains the vector of names, I get back "NULL". Could this illustrate the problem?

Comment: Great. Also, the manual for dotchart says "labels 
a vector of labels for each point. For vectors the default is to use names(x) and for matrices the row labels dimnames(x)[[1]].", so I think my argument isn't quite correct

Comment: Here is something to check out. When you describe your data you have `x.sample` (lower case x). Your setNames statement has `d$X.sample` (upper case X).  Is your code consistent?  I had made _both_ of these be `X` (upper case).  If you had that wrong, it would produce the result that you got (no names)

Comment: Ah, I see, my file is not being read as a numeric vector or matrix, which is what is needed for dotchart to work, and the labels function to work. My file is being read as a dataframe. Just trying out how to force to a matrix but still keep my y axis labels

Comment: I used a data.frame when I made the chart above.    Did you check about x.sample vs X.sample?

Comment: I'll just add that I had to re-save my files with headings in them so that the data was read properly for dotchart.